# How to analyse using foreach loop on this type of multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the values from this multidimentional array.its pattern is as follows by using `print_r($link_array);`

The array is actually from the google rss api.

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => World Cup draw -- group-by-group analysis [link] =>          http://www.dawn.com/news/1061096/world-cup-draw-group-by-group-analysis [author] => [publishedDate] => Sat, 07 Dec 2013 02:31:51 -0800 [contentSnippet] => GROUP A: Brazil, Croatia, Mexico, Cameroon - Having hit form in spectacular style earlier this year by winning the ... [content] =>asdfasdf
[categories] => Array ( [0] => Sport/Football ) ) [1] => Array ( [mediaGroups] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [contents] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://i.dawn.com/primary/2013/12/52a2f7a584e2a.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [medium] => image [title] => Brazil's head coach Luiz Felipe Scolari. -Photo by AP [thumbnails] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://i.dawn.com/primary/2013/12/52a2f7a584e2a.jpg ) ) ) ) ) )
```

I have tried following three ways

```
echo $link_array[0];
   echo $link_array[title];

          foreach($link_array as $key=>$value){

           echo $key;

    }
```

Pleas help.

Comment: Looks more like PHP than jQuery ?

Comment: if this javascript..? try using jQuery $.each function

Comment: I used that.but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is mostly right, however you're printing its keys, just try acessing `value['title']` and you'll get the title:

```
foreach($link_array as $key=>$value){
       echo $value['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first assign the array to a variable.

```
$link_array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => World Cup draw -- group-by-group analysis [link] =>          http://www.dawn.com/news/1061096/world-cup-draw-group-by-group-analysis [author] => [publishedDate] => Sat, 07 Dec 2013 02:31:51 -0800 [contentSnippet] => GROUP A: Brazil, Croatia, Mexico, Cameroon - Having hit form in spectacular style earlier this year by winning the ... [content] =>asdfasdf
[categories] => Array ( [0] => Sport/Football ) ) [1] => Array ( [mediaGroups] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [contents] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://i.dawn.com/primary/2013/12/52a2f7a584e2a.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [medium] => image [title] => Brazil's head coach Luiz Felipe Scolari. -Photo by AP [thumbnails] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://i.dawn.com/primary/2013/12/52a2f7a584e2a.jpg ) ) ) ) ) )
```

then you can do excatly as you have done

```
foreach ($link_array as $key=>$value):
    echo $key . " - " . $value;
endforeach;
```

but this will not display your internal arrays within the array. For that you would need to do a for each inside a foreach if `is_array($link_array[$key]))`

```
foreach ($link_array as $key=>$value):
    $new = $link_array[$key];
    if (is_array($new)):
        foreach ($new as $key1=>$value1):
            echo $key1 . " - " . $value1;
        endforeach;
    else: 
        echo $key . " - " . $value;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

You can go as many levels deep as you want and change the echo.

Answer (score 0):

You could also call a function within a function:

```
// call it
loopfor($link_array);
function loopfor ($DATA) {
    foreach ($DATA as $key=>$value):
        if (is_array($DATA[$key])):
            loopfor($DATA[$key]);
        else:
            echo $key . " - " . $value;
        endif;
    endforeach;
}
```